# What does Image width is not in range Valid range is from 1 to 2048 mean?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, arcgis-silverlight-api

We are facing an issue on ESRI Silverlight (v 3.1) and ArcGIS Server 10 SP4 based web application. Few of the users complaining that map is not being displayed in their machine. When I investigated fiddler log, map service request throws 404 error . Below is the detailed

> *Error Specified format is not supported  Code: 400 Image width is not in range. Valid range is from 1 to 2048.*

Users are using dual monitors and different browser zoom levels, so few people are OK and few others facing trouble in viewing map layers, how to fix this issue for different screen resolutions and browser zoom levels?

I am looking for comprehensive solution for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

2048 is the default value of ArcGIS Server's MaxImageHeight/Width parameter, in the service config file. You are likely going over this!

You need to reduce your image or increase the parameter value to allow the map service to serve the larger format!